# Weird image after resuming from suspend

Tags: linux, suspend

So when I resume from suspend, I very rarely see an unknown image for less than a second before it disappears. I have managed to record this happening and here is an image of what I saw. I have never seen this image before, so it can't be from a video I had open or something like that.

[image: image of what appears to be three guys playing tennis]

It looks like three guys playing table tennis. It is so weird it is almost unbelievable.

Any ideas or even how to figure out the cause for this?
I am running Linux with Gnome and systemd, in case that makes a difference. I have also inspected the network traffic, logs, etc. and didn't see anything really odd.

Comment: The weirdest part is this is tennis for *three*.

Comment: Is it a second hand laptop? Looks like burn in from wallpaper or something, although that shouldn’t remain for this long.

Comment: The person I bought it from barely used it and that was over 1 year ago, so burn in might not be it. Here is a gif of what happens: https://imgur.com/a/Jt6Kz

Comment: @wierdfrosty: Are you sure there are absolutely no signs of it if you view a solid dark grey background with the brightness turned up?

Comment: @JamesP I tried a background of #040404, and went full brightness but there was no sign of it. I will try updating from Mac OS side. Thanks for all the help.